# Technical differences between EFA and CFA

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I've been looking for the answer everywhere but can't seem to find it.
When you do EFA, you'll get how much variance is explained by every single factor (and by the entire factor model as well). When you do CFA, you'll only get the R-squared statistics for every item. But I can't seem to find how much variance is explained by every factor or by the model itself in CFA. I'm almost sure now that there is a reason why you won't get these statistics but maybe someone can explain me this? I would be very thankful.

I just summed up all the R-squared statistics of the items and then divided the result by the number of items.. (after reading some forums which told that this is the variance explained by the CFA model) but it does not seem right to me...

Comment: Hi Katie welcome to the site, are you asking about a specific R package for doing EFA/CFA?  If it's a more general question about statistics you might get better answers from the Cross Validated site.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute composite reliability (e.g., McDonalds omega for congeneric factor models) for a given factor in CFA based on the standardized item loadings. Composite reliability indicates how reliable the entire set of items (sum or average) is for a given factor.

Since in CFA each item typically loads only onto a single factor (there are few if any cross-loadings in most CFA models), the question of how much of the total item variance is explained by each factor is less relevant than in EFA.